# Why is cweagans/composer-patches not installing this patch?

Tags: composer, 10

I'm trying to apply different patches but after the command `composer install` nothing happens. Output:

```
Installing dependencies from the lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
42 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
  * Homepage: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal
  * Support:
    * docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html
    * chat: https://www.drupal.org/node/314178
```

For example: I'm trying to apply a patch in my code for the module CKEditor CodeSnippet:
https://www.drupal.org/project/codesnippet/issues/3269387

part of the composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    // some code
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^2.0",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.3",
        "drupal/codesnippet": "^1.8",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^10.0",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^10.0",
        // some code
    },
    // some code
    "config": {},
    "extra": {
        "patches": {
            "drupal/codesnippet": {
                "https://www.drupal.org/i/3269387 - Drupal 10 & CKEditor 5 support": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2023-04-27/3356929-2_0.patch"
            }
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
    // some code
```

Also for testing, I found some patch for the admin toolbar module and tried to apply it but it also doesn't apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that **cweagans/composer-patches** was not installed. After I wrote the command `composer require cweagans/composer-patches` the patches are now applied after the command `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

It think this is because:

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in
> composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is
> recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`. Nothing to install, update or remove

That means the package has already been installed in that codebase in the desired version. Because of that you actually have to tell Composer to re-install the package so that the patch will be applied.

Do what it says: `composer update drupal/codesnippet`

An upcoming version of cweagans/composer-patches will have [a composer sub-command that allows re-patching](https://docs.cweagans.net/composer-patches/usage/recommended-workflows/#apply-patches-added-to-the-project-by-someone-else).

Comment: I wrote a command. `composer update drupal/codesnippet` and got: "Nothing to modify in lock file" and "Nothing to install, update or remove". Also for testing, I found some patch for the admin toolbar module and tried to apply it but it also doesn't apply.

Comment: Is cweagans/composer-patches installed at all? I don't see it in your composer.json.

Comment: Go nuclear: `composer remove drupal/codesnippet; composer require drupal/codesnippet`

Comment: `composer why cweagans/composer-patches`. If it says it's not installed, apply palm to forehead and delete this question :)